# Is it possible to watch the same distant star's supernova event twice?

Tags: spacetime, time-dilation, supernova

Usually relativistic time dilation effects require something traveling near the speed of light. But the high speed requirement can be replaced with a high distance requirement instead. Traveling away from a distant location will let you observe older distant events than when traveling towards a distant location.

What I think this means is if you observe a supernova that's at just the right distance away while the Earth is traveling away from the event during its orbit then wait half a year for when the Earth is traveling in the opposite direction, you'll sweep another slice of space from spacetime that also contains the supernova event. You should be able to adjust what distance this works for by waiting for different velocity differences during orbit or sending a satellite up to have more control over the velocity differences and wait times.

Do we have any photographed evidence of the same supernova exploding twice by carefully using the time dilation effects of small velocity differences across large distances?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I think this means is if you observe a supernova that's at just the right distance away while the Earth is traveling away from the event during its orbit then wait half a year for when the Earth is traveling in the opposite direction, **you'll sweep another slice of space from spacetime that also contains the supernova event.**

This is a great way of thinking, and if you turn it around, you'll see the answer to your question.

For convenience, let's pretend the supernova happens at a single point in spacetime. The light from the supernova travels out along the forward light cone of that point.

Meanwhile, a few thousand light years away, the sun and the earth are hurtling through space and time. Since they're both massive objects, their worldlines are timelike curves. The earth's worldline spirals around the sun's, as sketched below.

People on earth will see the supernova at the point in spacetime where the earth passes through the supernova's forward light cone. Now, here's an important geometry fact: **in flat spacetime, no timelike curve can pass through a given forward light cone more than once.** No matter how weird and curvy the earth's worldline looks, it can't pass through the supernova's forward light cone twice, so people on earth only get one chance to watch the fireworks.

[image: Spacetime diagram of a supernova seen from our solar system]

As QuadmasterXLII and Cort Ammon have pointed out, the situation is different in curved spacetime. When spacetime is warped, it's possible for a timelike curve to pass through a given forward light cone many times.

The "light echoes" Kyle Kanos mentioned can occur even in flat spacetime: they happen when the light from the supernova hits a reflective object, like a cloud of dust. The light that hits the dust cloud scatters off in all directions, forming a second light cone. Now people on earth can see light from the supernova twice: once when the earth passes through the forward light cone of the supernova, and once when it passes through the forward light cone of the scattering event.

Comment: Is that you're own drawing? I LOVE it! Kind of reminds me of the 1960s Batman TV series.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Yes, I made it in Inkscape; everything that looks hand-drawn was done on a drawing tablet. I'm glad you like it! I'll keep 1960s television animation in mind as a backup career.

Answer (score 40):

You can't quite look back in time, unless you can outrun a photon.  If you think about it, the event being observed is marked by a release of photons forming a sphere like shape.  Once you are inside the sphere, you can observe the event.  However, once you are inside, the only way to get outside is to go faster than the wave-front of photons.  Unless you can get outside, you can't observe it again.

However, we can do better than that. We can view a supernova from multiple angles at once, using gravitational lensing!

http://newscenter.berkeley.edu/2015/03/05/distant-supernova-split-four-ways-by-gravitational-lens/

Comment: I misunderstood then. Perhaps only the relative movement of the observed event matters for when you receive the information of distant events?

Comment: It matters greatly when determining when events occur, and simultaneity.  However, those are topics discussing two different observing parties.  In this case, you have one observing party, seeking to run around the universe, so it only gets to see events unfold in one order.

Comment: But as mentioned in the article, gravitational lensing also allows to view a supernova from multiple angles *at* *different* *times* (in this case, with intervals on the order of decades), which contradicts your first paragraph. In other words, the wave front may look much more complicated than “sphere-like”.

Comment: This does raise the interesting question of what shape the photon shell has _after_ it passed the gravitaional lens. Apparently it gets "folded" such that it passes through us several times. But does it stay connected after folding? Are some of our observations because a "reversed" part of the photon shell sweeps past us, so we end up back "on the outside" of the deformed shell, topologically speaking? And how is that consistent with seeing an _even_ number of images?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, if there are two (or more) geodesics from the nova event to us, why should they be of equal length in the first place? Also, even if *I* observe from two angles simultanuously, the notion of simultanity is relativistically meaningless away from my personal position where both rays go through different points in space ...

Comment: @Hagen: I'm not denying the facts, merely wondering what the explanation for those facts looks like in the photon-shell picture,

Comment: Good call on the sphere, @EmilJeřábek.  I called it "sphere like" in a attempt to hand wave away the topology, but you caught me!  When space distorts enough to cause that shell to intersect itself, my choice of words breaks down.  As for being "reversed" or anything, the shell doens't quite work that way.  The most technically "right" version of that shell is a region whose events can be "causally sequenced after the supernova," but that phrasing doesn't help much for intuition.  However, it does lead to neat tricks.  Consider, if you see 3 versions of the same nova...

Comment: ..you could get enough information to figure out where the nova was, and how long ago it occured.  If you then knew there was a gravitational lens effect which bent light along an even longer path, you could predict where and when it would appear again in the night sky.  This would lead to the appearance that you "predicted the future," but in reality, the information had already arrived with the first viewing.  All you did was process it.

Comment: With conventional lenses from what I understand, the time required for light that comes off a particular point on an object to reach its corresponding focal point is independent of the exact path taken to get there; path lengths vary, but the shorter paths spend more time in a material where light travels more slowly.  Such behavior would not be true of a Fresnel lens, however; each disjoint ring would have a different focal time.  Do gravitational lenses have similar discontinuities?

Comment: I'd have to check my facts, but I believe the travel-time of light is path dependent.  It's a bit mucky with a conventional lens, but consider the double-slit experiment which demonstrates that photons taking different paths arrive at the objective surface in different phases.  This either requires the light to take different travel-times through each slit, or it requires the photons to change frequency along the way.  However, I would not expect gravitational lensing to have Fresnel lens style discontinuities.  Those particular discontinuities come from discontinuities in the geometry.

Comment: +1 "Unless you can get outside, you can't observe it again." - Great Explanation

Answer (score 19):

You're not going to see the explosion twice, that's pretty much against the rules of SR and reference frames. However, with a lot of fortune, we can actually see the light from the remnant a second time (maybe more). Sorta

There are things called [light echoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_echo), which is an analog to the common acoustic echoes that we are all familiar with. When this occurs, what we observe is the light as it was (sans absorption effects) when the star exploded. And it's entirely based on the geometry of things near the supernova and our planet.

Suppose the yellow blob in the image below (from the linked Wiki page) is the supernova.

[image]

We typically see the light labeled A. However, if there is a [dust cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_dust) towards the right side (at either bend in paths B and C), then the light will take the long-way around and come to us much later.

What we see is rather beautiful:
[image]
(Light echo of [SN1987A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN_1987A), [source](http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/0/19697518-6514-11de-a13f-00144feabdc0.html))

The concentric rings are tell-tale signs of the light echo. The [light curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_curve) from the echoes can tell us a bit about the remnant type (e.g., Type I or Type II and all subclasses) and some characteristics of the dusty environment (due to absorptions).

Comment: [Can ducks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo#Duck.27s_quack) make a light echo?

Comment: @tpg2114 Only if they're floating in a dust cloud when they go supernova. MythBusters was unable to recreate that part of the myth, if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is clearly the answer. From the source you link: _"One bonus is that, given the peculiar nature of gravitational lensing, astronomers can tune in for a supernova replay within the next five years. This is because light can take various paths around and through a gravitational lens, arriving at Earth at different times. Computer modeling of this lensing cluster shows that the researchers missed opportunities to see the exploding star 50 years ago and again 20 years ago, but images of the explosion will likely repeat again in a few years."_

Answer (score 16):

One supernova has been observed 4 times, over the course of 20 years! This didn't involve the Earth's orbit. Instead, the supernova's light took 4 different routes from its source to Earth, the routes bending due to the gravity of galaxy clusters between the supernova and Earth. Because the lengths of these paths varied by up to 20 lightyears, the light travelling some paths took up to 20 years longer to reach us.

http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/06/science/astronomers-observe-supernova-and-find-theyre-watching-reruns.html?_r=0

Comment: This is pretty much the exact same answer [that Cort wrote](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/170467/25301) 11 hours prior to this one.

Comment: You are correct, I misread his answer the first time.

Answer (score 10):

Very simply put, in order to view any event twice, both occasions in absolute real time (ignoring the time the light took to reach you, directly from the event), you would need to outrun the photons, which entails faster-than-light travel.

Now, if you're willing to accept less than real time, it is absolutely possible, though it gets less and less practical as you add more delay in trying to separate the two viewings in time. For example, you could:

- **Use a giant mirror:** If you were to be positioned 7.5 kilometers from the event, armed with a space telescope and you positioned a large mirror 17987540km away, you would see the event with the naked eye about 25 microseconds (25.0173071 microseconds) after it happened, and your telescope would see it reflected through the mirror about 2 minutes after it happened (119.999975s).
- **Slow down the light:** As light travels through a material with a large refractive index (technically any material, given a refractive index greater than 1), it is slowed down. If you distributed a material with a sufficiently large refractive index between you and the event, but only on one side (take your pick, there's no right or left in space), you could see the event first looking around the material, and then again looking through it. In fact, Harvard physicist Lene Hau used this method in 1999 to bike alongside light, and [beat it to its destination](http://www.seas.harvard.edu/directory/hau). Unfortunately, her method would be very difficult to use in space, where fluctuating temperatures and vast distances would prevent the use of any conventional Earth-borne material.
- **Store the image:** The next possible solution, and the most practical, is to simply store the event on camera. There are also a [number of chemical processes which similarly reproduce images](http://www.chemheritage.org/discover/media/magazine/articles/28-2-silver-and-sunlight.aspx?page=2), though as a general rule a digital camera (or space telescope) will produce a far better image.

**In short, there are good reasons why scientists use cameras (often space telescopes).**

Answer (score 1):

Similar to, but perhaps more repeatable on-demand than Quadmaster's answer:

After you see the supernova, just look at a **black hole** somewhere "to the side" (not along the line between the supernova and you) and compensate for the distortion.

A black hole, like a lens, bends light traveling near enough to be affected by its gravity (in our case, we want it to bend and pass without encountering the event-horizon). The hypotenuse of a triangle is never quite as long as the sum of the other two sides, so think of the photons from the original viewing traveling along the hypotenuse, and the blackhole as being the right-angle (though it doesn't have to necessarily be a right-angle).

The black hole allows you to view photons from the supernova which were emitted at the same time as your original observation...and these traveled a much further distance, so they'll arrive later for your convenience.