# Is it possible to witness supernova events from the past? Do they repeat?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, supernova

Astrophysicist I know recorded one in 2008. Later found to be exactly as one that happened in 1988. Could this actually be the same? Do they repeat?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to watch the same distant star's supernova event twice?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170464/)

Comment: There is one supernova that has been observed at 5 different times because of gravitational lensing. Light from the supernova was bent into different paths that took different amounts of time to reach us. This was important because it provides a third way to measure the rate of expansion of the universe. Currently the other two disagree with each other. See this Veritasium video for more info - [How One Supernova Measured The Universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljoeOLuX6Z4)

Comment: @mmesser314 that is mentioned in the top answer of the linked duplicate ;)

Comment: @KyleKanos - Right in front of my nose and I didn;t see it. Well here is something new. JWST has found another multiply imaged supernova. https://www.universetoday.com/160353/jwst-sees-the-same-supernova-three-times-in-an-epic-gravitational-lens/

Answer (score 0):

Supernovas blow up only once, but there are a whole class of less-powerful events (originally called *novas*) that can and do repeat.

These are generated when for example the accretion disc surrounding a massive object fills with ripped-up matter on its way to oblivion. Then the disc pours out a huge amount of thermal radiation extending all the way into the X-ray range. When that meal of matter is scavenged up by the massive object, the light goes out and the nova dims out until another big chunk of matter gets captured, the accretion disc fills up, and starts radiating again.

Comment: You are describing dwarf novae - these aren't the most luminous, or even the most common, type of nova.

Comment: @profrob, post your answer and I'll delete mine. I'd like to know what the right answer is- NN